Angular imported constant is undefined
I have a custom icon library created using https://github.com/kreuzerk/svg-icon-library-starter
I have the following import in my TxIconRegistry where I am using completeIconSet array to initialize the registry.
import { TxIcon, completeIconSet }  from 'custom-icons';

However, completeIconSet turns out to be undefined.
This is the tree of node_modules/custom_icons folder
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   ├── complete-icon-set.ts
│   ├── tx-icon.model.ts
│   └── txIcon-....icon.ts
├── index.d.ts
├── index.mjs
├── index.ts
└── package.json

Any idea why completeIconSet is undefined?
completeIconSet is a constant array exporting all custom icons
/*  this file was generated by svg-to-ts */
import { TxIcon } from './tx-icon.model';
import { txIcon... } from './txIcon-....icon';
import { txIconBuilding } from './txIcon-building.icon'; 
export const completeIconSet: TxIcon[] = [ txIcon...as TxIcon, ];

Thanks for your help.

What is completeIconSet?

Is the issue actually that the files in the published package are .ts rather than compiled js?

Do you set completeIconSet anywhere? Because that would explain the error message (undefined)

Turns out it was a few bits missing. This is how I solved it.

Added tsc to compile generated ts to js.
Removed "type": "module" from package json.

This is what my tscconfig.json looks like:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "./dist/icons",
    "outDir": "./dist/lib",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./dist/icons"
  ]
}

